# making a Pandas while loop faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a while loop which runs through a data frame A of 30000 rows and updates another data frame B and uses dataframe B for further iterations. its taking too much time. want to make it faster! any ideas

```py
for x in range(0, dataframeA.shape[0]):

    AuthorizationID_Temp = dataframeA["AuthorizationID"].iloc[x]
    Auth_BeginDate = dataframeA["BeginDate"].iloc[x]
    Auth_EndDate = dataframeA["EndDate"].iloc[x]
    BeginDate_Temp = pd.to_datetime(Auth_BeginDate).date()
    ScriptsFlag = dataframeA["ScriptsFlag"].iloc[x]
    Legacy_PlacementID = dataframeA["Legacy_PlacementID"].iloc[x]
    Legacy_AncillaryServicesID = dataframeA["Legacy_AncillaryServicesID"].iloc[x]
    ProviderID_Temp = dataframeA["ProviderID"].iloc[x]
    SRSProcode_Temp = dataframeA["SRSProcode"].iloc[x]
    Rate_Temp = dataframeA["Rate"].iloc[x]

    Scripts2["BeginDate1_SC"] = pd.to_datetime(Scripts2["BeginDate_SC"]).dt.date
    Scripts2["EndDate1_SC"] = pd.to_datetime(Scripts2["EndDate_SC"]).dt.date
    # BeginDate_Temp = BeginDate_Temp.date()
    # EndDate_Temp = EndDate_Temp.date()

    Scripts_New_Modified1 = Scripts2.loc[
        ((Scripts2["ScriptsFlag_SC"].isin(["N", "M"])) & (Scripts2["AuthorizationID_SC"] == AuthorizationID_Temp))
        & ((Scripts2["ProviderID_SC"] == ProviderID_Temp) & (Scripts2["SRSProcode_SC"] == SRSProcode_Temp)),
        :,
    ]

    Scripts_New_Modified = Scripts_New_Modified1.loc[
        (Scripts_New_Modified1["BeginDate1_SC"] == BeginDate_Temp)
        & ((Scripts_New_Modified1["EndDate1_SC"] == EndDate_Temp) & (Scripts_New_Modified1["Rate_SC"] == Rate_Temp)),
        "AuthorizationID_SC",
    ]

    if ScriptsFlag == "M":

        if Legacy_PlacementID is not None:

            InsertA = insertA(AuthorizationID_Temp, BeginDate_Temp, EndDate_Temp, Units_Temp, EndDate_Temp_DO)

            dataframeB = dataframeB.append(InsertA)

            print("ScriptsTemp6 shape is {}".format(dataframeB.shape))

        # else:

        # ScriptsTemp6 = ScriptsTemp5.copy()

        # print('ScriptsTemp6 shape is {}'.format(ScriptsTemp6.shape))

        if Legacy_AncillaryServicesID is not None:

            InsertB = insertB(AuthorizationID_Temp, BeginDate_Temp, EndDate_Temp, Units_Temp, EndDate_Temp_DO)

            dataframeB = dataframeB.append(InsertB)

            print("ScriptsTemp7 shape is {}".format(dataframeB.shape))

        dataframe_New = dataframeB.loc[
            ((dataframeB["ScriptsFlag"] == "N") & (dataframeB["AuthorizationID"] == AuthorizationID_Temp))
            & ((dataframeB["ProviderID"] == ProviderID_Temp) & (dataframeB["SRSProcode"] == SRSProcode_Temp)),
            :,
        ]

        dataframe_New1 = dataframe_New.loc[
            (pd.to_datetime(dataframe_New["BeginDate"]).dt.date == BeginDate_Temp)
            & ((pd.to_datetime(dataframe_New["EndDate"]).dt.date == EndDate_Temp_DO) & (dataframe_New["Rate"] == Rate_Temp)),
            "AuthorizationID",
        ]

        # PLAATN = dataframeA.copy()

        Insert1 = insert1(dataframe_New1, BeginDate_Temp, AuthorizationID_Temp, EndDate_Temp, Units_Temp, EndDate_Temp_DO)

        if Insert1.shape[0] > 0:

            dataframeB = dataframeB.append(Insert1.iloc[0])

        # else:

        # ScriptsTemp8 = ScriptsTemp7

        print("ScriptsTemp8 shape is {}".format(dataframeB.shape))

        dataframe_modified1 = dataframeB.loc[
            ((dataframeB["ScriptsFlag"] == "M") & (dataframeB["AuthorizationID"] == AuthorizationID_Temp))
            & ((dataframeB["ProviderID"] == ProviderID_Temp) & (dataframeB["SRSProcode"] == SRSProcode_Temp)),
            :,
        ]

        dataframe_modified = dataframe_modified1.loc[
            (dataframe_modified1["BeginDate"] == BeginDate_Temp)
            & ((dataframe_modified1["EndDate"] == EndDate_Temp_DO) & (dataframe_modified1["Rate"] == Rate_Temp)),
            "AuthorizationID",
        ]

        Insert2 = insert2(
            dataframe_modified,
            Scripts_New_Modified,
            AuthorizationID_Temp,
            BeginDate_Temp,
            EndDate_Temp,
            Units_Temp,
            EndDate_Temp_DO,
        )

        if Insert2.shape[0] > 0:
            dataframeB = dataframeB.append(Insert2.iloc[0])
```

dataframeA having 30000 rows

dataframeB should be inserted with new rows every iteration(30000 iterations) from DataframeA

updated dataframeB should be used in middle of each iteration for filtering conditions

insertA and InsertB are two functions which has additional filtering

it takes too much time to run for 30000 rows so

so it takes more time to run. 
provide suggestions for making the loop faster in terms of execution time

Comment: You're not really using Pandas' features here at all, so maybe you should rethink this without Pandas.

Comment: Also, the functions `insert1()` and `insert2()` you're using aren't defined in the example.